# React alternative to ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I have a this simple non-react ES6 class in a react-project that i use to create medication instances.

```
export default class Medication {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }
  someFunction() {} 
}

const medData = [{name: "med1"}, {name: "med2"}, {name: "med3"}];
const meds = medData.map(med => new Medication(med));
```

I also have a setting-context or provider that keeps settings that are loaded once from a backend and provides it via a context.

```
export const SettingContext = React.createContext();

export default class SettingsProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {settings: {...}};
  }
  ...
  render() {
    return (
        <SettingContext.Provider value={{setting: this.state.settings}}>
          {this.props.children}
        </SettingContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there any way to use this context inside the Medication class, so that i can use the settings in there? What would be an alternative to ES6 classes where I could then use the context?

Comment: Where are you initializing these instances? If you're doing so inside of a React component you could pass context values as parameters, however you cannot use context outside of a component. I've generally found that React does not work well with generic ES6 classes, as it usually conflicts with managing your state in React. Class methods that change state need to be reflected in React's state to trigger necessary changes in the DOM.

Comment: in the non-react class use `const context = React.useContext(SettingContext)` then you have access to it. for typed version `const context: React.ContextType<typeof SettingContext> = React.useContext(SettingContext);`

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi that only works inside a function of that ES6 class but that works for me, so thank you. It does not work inside the constructor or as a static value.

Comment: @ChrisB. Yes i initialize it inside a react component, but i would like to have the settings inside the class and not pass it through a function. I also got the feeling that React does not work well with generic ES6 classes. I'm new in react and i'm interested in how to build a good architecture. Maybe you do not write simple classes in react but rather function libraries that you import and use. I don't know =)

Answer (score 2):

Create context file

```js
//context.jsx
import React from "react";
export const initialSetting = { foo: true };
export const SettingContext = React.createContext({
  settings: initialSetting,
  setSettings: () => {}
});
```

and then create High Order Component

```js
//HocModule.jsx
import React from "react";
import { SettingContext } from "./context.jsx";
export const HocModule = props => {
  const [settings, setSettings] = React.useState();
  const settingsValue = React.useMemo(() => ({ settings, setSettings }), [
    settings,
    setSettings
  ]);

  return (
    <SettingContext.Provider value={settingsValue}>
      {props.children}
    </SettingContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now any module get set context

```js
//AnyModule.jsx

import { SettingContext } from "./context.jsx";
import { HocModule } from "./HocModule";

export const AnyModule = () => {
  const { settings, setSettings } = React.useContext(SettingContext);
  return (
    <HocModule>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(settings)}</div>
    </HocModule>
  );
};

export default AnyModule;
```

Comment: I've tried that, that's what @ Amir-Mousavi said. that works so far but in the tests I get this error message: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

Answer (score -2):

May be you can try this:-

```
  import { SettingContext } from "import_from_the_module_it_is";
    export default class Medication {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }
  someFunction() {
// use your context
const setting = this.context;
} 
}
Medication.contextType = SettingContext;
```